# Twitter-Bootstrap V4 navbar dropdown missing styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, it appears that V4 has no documentation on using navbar dropdowns. Following the the V3 docs, the navbar on V4 does drop down on click, but appears to be unstyled. How can I get the dropdown to appear properly as shown [in the V3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)? I'm assuming that the css selector has changed; if that's the case, how would I go about finding the new undocumented selector?

This is what it currently looks like with V3 classes on the V4 library:

[image: Bootstrap navbar dropdown unstyled]

The HTML used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HelloWorld</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false">1<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false">2<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false">3<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it's not documented, because not finished on V4?

Comment: But why not keep the v3 until it's finished? The JS works, and they did of launch V4 alpha for public use so I can't imagine that this is just partially MIA

Comment: V4 is rewritten from V3. SASS instead of LESS, flexbox instead of display: table and so on...

Comment: Ah I see, darn. Are there any alternatives for if I have too much stuff in the navbar? Or should I just delete this and use V3? It just feels like a waste to start V3 when V4 is so close...

Answer (score 1):

You are using 
`<li> and <ul>` whereas the documentation suggests to use `<div> and <a>` tags instead

```
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        1
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/fqfxc0nu/4/) for reference

Edit2: Ok so u missed the classes `btn and btn-success`. Also add css rule

`.dropdown { display:inline-block;}`

Edit3: [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/fqfxc0nu/5/): Dropdown 1 with `<a>` instead of `<button>`

Comment: I don't think that it matters, bootstrap is based on classes, not on DOM elements names.

Comment: I made the changes, the dropdowns are on the same line now but still appear unalignment with the rest of the navbar, and the right nav is still pushed one line down.

Comment: Create a fiddle or update the image to show the current alignment issue

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Use class nav-item with each <div> , <li> to make them all come in a single horizontal row

Comment: Is there any way to use the regular nav-items instead of buttons?

Comment: Update 5: https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/fqfxc0nu/5/   Dropdown 1 using <a> , Dropdown 2 using <button>, every element has nav-item so come in single line. Mark answer as correct if this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">HelloWorld</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">1<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">2<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">3<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grid</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working Plnkr: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zNr0yPfDNlspthUgmAQd?p=preview)

Comment: Wait, but this is using Bootstrap 3... :(

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with bootstrap 4? Will check it.

Comment: The only thing i added to your code was: "<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">" and this makes sure that the navbar is collapsed on small devices. Your code works fine at my end using bootstrap 3. Since bootstrap 4 is still not available as a compiled version, I can't try it at my end with bootstrap 4 without putting a lot of effort in it. So unless you create a fiddle or host your problem somewhere, it's hard to provide a solution.